# youtube embed links not showing up in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, embed

I have tried to display an youtube embedded iframe of a link (that a user would input and save in a form)

The embedded video doesnt show up. All i get is blank space.

Here is my code

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src= "<%= video.link %>" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have checked the source code

screenshot here http://screencast.com/t/gmQAiFHEj

In the source you can see it displaying the URLS of the youtube videos but how can i get it render?

Answer (score 7):

The YouTube URL you're using is not a proper embed URL.

- **Wrong:** http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKvlBCfi_v8
- **Right:** http://www.youtube.com/embed/VKvlBCfi_v8

YouTube blocks direct embed requests when using the direct URL to the YouTube page.

See the example below showing the difference (the above **Right** URL works fine).

- http://fiddle.jshell.net/2RvGE/show/

Comment: +1 for the right answer. Mine is just talking around the subject :-)

Answer (score 3):

Deefour is right. I am posting an answer just to show you a better way to display youtube videos (it is going to be easier for you)

Create a partial _youtube.html.erb and paste:

```
<iframe width="490" height="275" src="<%= url %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Then add in you Application controller:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def youtube_video(url)
    render :partial => 'shared/youtube', :locals => { :url => url }
  end 
end
```

And then in your views call:

```
<%= youtube_video @video.url %>
```

But yes, try not to copy wrong link, use, links like:

```
"http://www.youtube.com/embed/NWHfY_lvKIQ"
```

Comment: This is only really 'better' if OP is embedding youtube videos all over their application. Otherwise IMO this is overkill.

Comment: I agree. I have seen that he is using table and a number of `<td>` and `<tr>` at least 4 x 4 rows/columns in his example, so I tought it doesn't hurt to say :) but thank you for pointing that out!